# AlarmManager: set the time to stop the notification

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm having doubts about how to stop AlarmManager. I would like to start in "x" hours and stop at "y" hours, set by the user. I know the existence of the ".cancel" function, but I do not know how to set the stop time in "y" hours.

**onCreate**

```
final EditText chooseTime = findViewById(R.id.etChooseTime);
        chooseTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(AlarmeAguaActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, final int hourOfDay, final int minutes) {
                        chooseTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minutes);
                        Button btnIniciarNotificacao = findViewById(R.id.btnIniciarNotificacao);
                        btnIniciarNotificacao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                configuraAlarme(hourOfDay, minutes);
                                Toast.makeText(AlarmeAguaActivity.this, "Notificação ativa!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 0, 0, false);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
        Button btnPararTimer = findViewById(R.id.btnPararTimer);
        btnPararTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pararAlarme();
            }
        });
```

**Stop and Pause**

```
private void configuraAlarme(int hora, int minuto) {
        try {
            alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
            alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

            /* Aqui é aonde setamos o horário de início das notificações*/
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);

            /*
             * Nosso alarme vai funcionar de uma em uma hora de acordo c/ o
             * horário pré definido pelo o usuário
             * EXEMPLO = 1000 * 60 * 1 = notificação a cada 1 min.
             * */
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60, alarmIntent);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "configuraAlarme: ");
        }
    }

    private void pararAlarme() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Suas notificações foram canceladas!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create the alarm manager intent you can pass an extra parameter with the end time, for example

```
alarmIntent.putExtra("end", System.currentTimeMillis() + 60*60*1000); //1 hour from current time
```

Of course, you can replace the end time with the time that the user chooses, but it must be in milliseconds